# Error while executing sed command

Tags: shell, sed, cygwin

I am trying to execute script with commands:

```
sed -i "USER/c\export USER=${signumid}" .bashrc

sed -i "DEVENVHOME=$/c\export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-/home/${signumid}/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}" .bashrc
```

I want to replace the line with string "`USER`" in `.bashrc` with `export USER=${signumid}` where `$signumid` variable is being provided through Cygwin prompt.  Similarly I want to replace line with string `DEVENVHOME=$` with `export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-/home/${signumid}/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}` in `.bashrc` file, where `$signumid` variable is provided through Cygwin prompt.

But I am getting following errors on Cygwin termminal.:

```
 sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `U'
 sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command
```

Comment: Yes, those are syntax errors. It's not *at all* clear what you are hoping that this invalid code should accomplish, so we cannot help you much more than restating what the error message already says.  You could improve your question by explaining what you want the program to do.

Comment: The substitute command is, by default, `s/replace-this/with-that/`.  The `sed` program is telling you that there is no command `U` in its repertoire; you should be using something like `sed -i 's/USER/export USER='"${signumid}"/ .bashrc` instead.  It isn't clear what the `c` and ``\`` are meant to be doing.  Similarly in the second command, except that you probably shouldn't use `/` as the character since the replacement string contains it; use `%` or `@` or something else (control-A?) instead.

Comment: I tried executing        sed -i 's/USER/export USER='"${signumid}"/ .bashrc               ,but its giving error        sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown option to `s', now.

Comment: Sounds like `signumid` contains a slash.  This is already covered in my answer, at the very end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general syntax of a `sed` script is a sequence of *address* *command* *arguments* statements (separated by newline or semicolon).  The most common *command* is the `s` substitution command, with an empty *address,* so we can perhaps assume that that is what you want to use here.  You seem to be attempting to interpolate a shell variable `$signumid` which adds a bit of a complication to this exposition.

If your strings were simply static text, it would make sense to use single quotes; then, the shell does not change the text within the quotes at all.  The general syntax of the `s` command is `s/regex/replacement/` where the slash as the argument separator is just a placeholder, as we shall soon see.

```
sed -i 's/.*USER.*/export USER=you/
    s% DEVENVHOME=\$%export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-/home/you/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}%' .bashrc
```

This will find any line with `USER` and substitute the entire line with `export USER=you`; then find any line which contains `DEVENVHOME=$` (with a space before, and a literal dollar character) and replace *the matched expression* with the long string.  Because the substitution string uses slashes internally, we use a different regex separator `%` -- alternatively, we could backslash-escape the slashes which are not separators, but as we shall see, that quickly becomes untenable when we add the following twist.  Because the dollar sign has significance as the "end of line" metacharacter in regular expressions, we backslash-escape it.

I have ignored the `c\` in your attempt on the assumption that it is simply a misunderstanding of `sed` syntax.  If it is significant, what do you hope to accomplish with it?  `c\export` is not a valid Bash command, so you probably mean something else, but I cannot guess what.

Now, to interpolate the value of the shell variable `signumid` into the replacement, we cannot use single quotes, because those inhibit interpolation.  You have correctly attempted to use double quotes instead (in your edited question), but that means we have to make some additional changes.  Inside double quotes, backslashes are processed by the shell, so we need to double all backslashes, or find alternative constructs.  Fortunately for us, the only backslash is in `\$` which can equivalently be expressed as `[$]`, so let's switch to that notation instead.  Also, where a literal dollar sign is wanted in the replacement string, we backslash-escape it in order to prevent the shell from processing it.

```
sed -i "s/.*USER.*/export USER=$signumid/
    s% DEVENVHOME=[$]%export DEVENVHOME=\${DEVENVHOME:-/home/$signumid/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}%" .bashrc
```

Equivalenty, you could use single quotes around the parts of the script which are meant to be untouched by the shell, and then put an adjacent double-quoted string around the parts which need interpolation, like

```
'un$touched*by$(the!shell)'"$signumid"'more$[complex]!stuff'
```

This final script still rests on a number of lucky or perhaps rather unlucky guesses about what you actually want.  On the first line, I have changed just `USER` to a regular expression which matches the entire line -- maybe that's not what you want?  On the other hand, the second line makes the opposite assumption, just so you can see the variations -- it only replaces the actual text we matched.  Probably one or the other needs to be changed.

Finally, notice how the two separate `sed` commands have been conflated into a single script.  Many newcomers do not realize that `sed` is a scripting language which accepts an arbitrary number of commands in a script, and simply treat it as a "replace" program with a funny syntax.

Another common source of confusion is the evaluation order.  The shell processes the double-quoted string even before `sed` starts to execute, so if you have mistakes in the quoting, you can easily produce syntax errors in the `sed` script which lead to rather uninformative error messages (because what `sed` tells you in the error message is based on what the script looks like after the shell's substutions).  For example, if `signumid` contains slashes, it will produce syntax errors, because `sed` will see those as terminating separators for the `s///` command.  An easy workaround is to switch to a separator which does not occur in the value of `signumid`.

Comment: A lot of this answer was composed before your recent edits, but I hope it still makes sense.