# AIX: sed with variables

Tags: sed, aix

I am writing AIX script and one particular line has problems:

```
sed -e "s/201[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/$DELIVERY/g" $DEPLOYMENT_PROPERTIES > FILE.new && mv FILE.new $DEPLOYMENT_PROPERTIES
```

It gives results like:

```
DeploymentDir=/TeemaPackages/PRODFIX/$DELIVERY/Teema_DWB1/WEB
```

I want `$DELIVERY` to disappear from the output string. The results must be something like this:

```
DeploymentDir=/TeemaPackages/PRODFIX/20141109/Teema_DWB1/WEB
```

I have tried various variations of writng the commadn, but still it outputs incorrect string. Any suggestions, why AIX sed can't see this variable correctly?

Comment: Are you sure you used double quotes?

Comment: Yes. I can't find this working on AIX

Comment: That, or the variable `DEPLOYMENT` contains the string `$DEPLOYMENT`.

Comment: The `sed` comcand simply executes whatever the shell passes in. If this fails, the problem is in the containing shell script, not in this actual `sed` command. You should be able to prove this to yourself easily by executing these dommand on the command line.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/33887260/874188

Comment: Tripleeee, it contains number like: 20141122

Comment: What shell (and version) are you running?

Comment: Output from `uname -a`  : `AIX teemadwb1 1 7 00C7CB374C00`
Shell: Bash

Comment: Do you restore the original $DEPLOYMENT_PROPERTIES after each try? When you tried it the first time with single quotes, the inputfile is changed.
Instead of redirecting first write to stdout until it works!

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo "$DEPLOYMENT"` and `grep DeploymentDir $DEPLOYMENT_PROPERTIES` ? Or test with ` set -x` ?